# Telemetry does not show up in Application Insights but gives an error instead

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

When i log information to application insights most of the time i get an error message. 
Error: **AI: Process was called on the TelemetrySink after it was disposed, the telemetry data was dropped.**

My application is a .net 6 asp.net app.

NuGet Packages:
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.21.0"
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Profiler.AspNetCore" Version="2.4.0"

Trace Properties
Event time  6-11-2022 10:30:16.390 (Local time)
Device type PC
Message AI: Process was called on the TelemetrySink after it was disposed, the telemetry data was dropped.
Severity level  Verbose
Telemetry type  trace
Operation name  POST Purchase/PurchaseTransaction
Source of synthetic traffic SDKTelemetry
Application version 1.0.0.0
Client IP address   0.0.0.0
City    Dublin
State or province   Dublin
Country or region   Ireland
Role instance   webwk000000
SDK version dotnetc:2.21.0-429
Sample rate 1
Custom Properties
AspNetCoreEnvironment   Production

I configured Application insights in my start up class as follow

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
     services.AddServiceProfiler();
 }
```

I log the information in my controller as follow

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("/api/purchase")]
    public class PurchaseController
    {

        private readonly ILogger<PurchaseController> _logger;

        public PurchaseController(ILogger<PurchaseController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpPost("purchase-transaction")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PurchaseTransaction([FromBody] GlassfyRequestDto dto)
        {
            string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(dto);
            _logger.LogInformation(jsonString);     <------
            _logger.LogError("PurchaseTransactionData", dto);
            
            return Ok(jsonString);
        }
    }


The GlassfyRequestDto Class

using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace WebApi.Controllers.Dto
{
    // https://docs.glassfy.io/docs/webhooks.
    public class GlassfyRequestDto
    {
        [JsonProperty("app_version")]
        public string AppVersion { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("appid")]
        public string Appid { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("appsFlyerId")]
        public string AppsFlyerId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("auto_renew_product_id")]
        public string AutoRenewProductId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("auto_renew_status")]
        public bool AutoRenewStatus { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("bundle_version")]
        public string BundleVersion { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("country_code")]
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("currency_code")]
        public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("customid")]
        public string Customid { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("date_ms")]
        public long DateMs { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("days")]
        public int Days { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("device")]
        public string Device { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("duration")]
        public int Duration { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("environment")]
        public string Environment { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("estimated")]
        public int Estimated { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("event_date")]
        public int EventDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("expiration_intent")]
        public string ExpirationIntent { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("expire_date_ms")]
        public long ExpireDateMs { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("grace_period_expires_date_ms")]
        public int GracePeriodExpiresDateMs { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("is_in_billing_retry_period")]
        public bool IsInBillingRetryPeriod { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("months")]
        public int Months { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("offer_code_ref_name")]
        public string OfferCodeRefName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("offeringid")]
        public string Offeringid { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("original_purchase_date_ms")]
        public long OriginalPurchaseDateMs { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("original_transaction_id")]
        public string OriginalTransactionId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("price")]
        public double Price { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("price_consent_status")]
        public string PriceConsentStatus { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("price_usd")]
        public double PriceUsd { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("productid")]
        public string Productid { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sdk_version")]
        public string SdkVersion { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sort_date_ms")]
        public long SortDateMs { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("source")]
        public string Source { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("store")]
        public string Store { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sub_platform")]
        public string SubPlatform { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("subscriberid")]
        public string Subscriberid { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("system_version")]
        public string SystemVersion { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public int Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("userunknown")]
        public bool Userunknown { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("vendorid")]
        public string Vendorid { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("web_order_line_item_id")]
        public string WebOrderLineItemId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("weeks")]
        public int Weeks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your `GlassfyRequestDto`  class file.

Comment: I added the class to the question.

Comment: Make sure you have added the Application Insights Connection String/Instrumentation key in `appsettings.json` file.

Comment: The Application Insights Connection String/Instrumentation key is present. And there is logging to APPI.

Answer (score 0):

Initially even i got the same issue.
[image]

- Add the below line of code in `Program.cs`

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(ITelemetryChannel), new ServerTelemetryChannel());
```

- In Azure portal create Application Insights.

Copy the  Application Insights `Connection String` or `Instrumentation key` in `AppSettings.json` file.

***appsettings.json***

```cs
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=Your key from Application Insights"
  }
}
```

***Program.cs***

```cs
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(ITelemetryChannel), new ServerTelemetryChannel());
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
builder.Services.AddServiceProfiler();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

***.csproj file***

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Profiler.AspNetCore" Version="2.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

- If you want to add the below code, we need to create an `ASP.NET Core Web API`

```cs
 [HttpPost("purchase-transaction")]
 [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]  
 [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden)]
```

- [`IActionResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-6.0#asynchronous-action-3) is a return type in the `ASP.NET Core Web API` .
- Created ASP.NET Core Web API

***My Controller.cs***

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Text.Json;
using WebApplication3.Controllers.Dto;

namespace WebApplication3.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        
        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpPost("purchase-transaction")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden)]
        public IActionResult PurchaseTransaction([FromBody] GlassfyRequestDto dto)
        {
            string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(dto);
            _logger.LogInformation(jsonString);
            _logger.LogError("PurchaseTransactionData", dto);

            return Ok(jsonString);
        }
    }
}
```

- Publish the App and enable `Application Insighs` in Azure Portal.
  [image]
- In `Application Insights` => `Transaction search` => click on `See all data in the last 24 hours`, you can see the traces.

[image]

- Even you can see the logs in `Application Insights` => `Logs`
  [image]

Comment: I tried this. And the first few times it does indeed log the data. But after the second / third time i post data it shows the error message again.

Comment: Did you add `AddSingleton` in `Program.cs` file?

Comment: No, in the ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) pipeline. But i think thats the same in this case

Comment: For .Net 6, all the code from `Startup.cs` is configured in `Program.cs`. Use the code which I have provided and check once.

Comment: Nope, i still get the error message after the second / third time i post data.

When i removed builder.Services.AddServiceProfiler(); the error message disappeared, but also the custom information logging doesn't come through.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core Web API only or ASP.NET Core App?

Comment: Im using ASP.NET Core Web API

Comment: I Changed my Logging and added ApplicationInsights :

 "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    }
  },

Now the data always arrives but the error message still shows up.

The only way i can get rid of the error message is when i remove builder.Services.AddServiceProfiler();