# Application Insights capturing ALL traces while appsettings.json level is set as Inforamtion

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-application-insights

I have a very simple Asp .Net API project where I am trying to add some trace logging.
I need some help with Application Insights configuration for that logging.
Right now its capturing ALL traces while in *appsettings.json* I have set the **Default** level to **Information**.

I have this code in my *Program.cs*

`services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();`

Followed by:

```
Trace.Listeners.Add(new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener.ApplicationInsightsTraceListener());
```

And the following in my *appsettings.json*:

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Microsoft": "Warning"
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning",
        "Microsoft": "Warning"
    }
}
```

I have these two packages in my *.csproj* file:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener" Version="2.22.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.22.0" />
```

I am expecting that only traces with level *Information* or above should get logged to Application Insights however I am also seeing every thing getting logged to Application Insights.
What do I need to do change the trace logging level globally?

I see this [Verbose messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjWr1.png) in my AI instance logged right now with the above config.

Comment: Information is the lowest level of logs no? So logically I would expect you to see everything

Comment: Ah sorry - ignore that - there's Debug and Trace too. I assume you mean you are seeing those?

Comment: Side note: that isn't strictly valid JSON, you have a trailing comma that is not needed.

Comment: thanks, removed the trailing comma now.

Comment: indeed @MattEvans I was expecting only Information and above. I am seeing everything like sql queries also in the tracing. It seems to be tracing everything.

Answer (score 0):

If Information level is kept , then it logs all the logs which are at information level and above. I have followed [Microsoft-document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-log-levels) and also [SO-thread's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74345671/17623802) answer provided by @Harshitha:

I have used below code in program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(ITelemetryChannel), new ServerTelemetryChannel());
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
builder.Services.AddServiceProfiler();
```

and added below lines in csproj:

```
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.21.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Profiler.AspNetCore" Version="2.4.0" />
```

Added logger code in controller:

```
 _logger.LogInformation("Hello Rithwik");
 _logger.LogTrace("Hello");
```

[image]

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "a2dec36e"
  }
  }
```

Only logs of information has been logged not trace level and all:

[image]

If you get other information use a level higher which only needs to be logged so that unwanted logging does not happen.

Comment: I am still seeing Verbose